# How to handle 2 same forms in one page?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have two input fields and two submit forms in a page and they do the same thing... just to get the email of the user for subscription.

I am using the following code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KrqrYB

```
$("input[type='text']").focus(function() {
  $(this).val(''); 
});

$(".message-validator").hide();

function validate() {
  var email = $(".input-set-input").val(),
      lastChar = email.substr(-1);
  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $(".message-validator").hide();
  } else {
    $(".message-validator").show();

    if (email === "") {
      $(".message-validator").text("Please provide a valid email.");
    } else {
      if (email.indexOf('@') > 0) {
        if (lastChar === "@") {
          $(".message-validator").text("Please enter a part following '@'.");
        } else {
          $(".message-validator").text("Please provide a valid email.");
        }
      } else {
        $(".message-validator").text("Please include an '@' in the email address.");
      }
    }

  }
  return false;
}

$("form").bind("submit", validate);

function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Is this a correct way to do it? Or should I create 2 different form classes and buttons and handle them differently?

Comment: Your `validate()` function works in a generic way. You need to target only the submitted form i.e. the form which triggered the `submit` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the form submit  handler function `this` will be the form the event occurred on.

So target only the elements that are in that form by using `find()`

Here's a small example as I don't plan to rewrite the whole thing

```
function validate() {
  var $form = $(this);// cache $(this) 
  var email = $form.find(".input-set-input").val()
   ......
 $form.find(".message-validator").hide();
```